# Using Pivot in SQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot

For example I have a table

**IPPARSED**
127
0
0
1

now I need to pivot the table so it can come like this

**1       2   3   4**
127   0   0   1

Can you help me how?

Comment: You might want to re-write your method that parses the IP address, if you can.  By placing them in a table in sequential order like that breaks relational database design rules.  Since each octet is related to each other, you should return them as a single row with four columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using case statements to pivot your table assuming the rows always go in that order:

```
SELECT (case when (<condition to match first octet>) then IPPARSED else END) as 1,
       (case when (<condition to match second octet>) then IPPARSED else END) as 2,
       (case when (<condition to match third octet>) then IPPARSED else END) as 3,
       (case when (<condition to match fourth octet>) then IPPARSED else END) as 4
FROM <insert_table_name_or_table_definition_here>
```

Cf. Anthony Mollinaro's [SQL Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009762/index.html) pg 365.

---

EDIT:  if your having trouble coming up with a `<condition to match (...) octet>`, you'll need to have the select operate on the results of a query that adds linenumbers to your table somehow.  In Oracle, you'd use the rownum psuedocolumn, but that doesn't exist in SQL Server.  It does appear that in SQL Server 2005 you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` built-in function as column, or possibly use the `IDENTITY(...)` function as a column in that query.

Answer (score 1):

Hi don't you have another column in your table to aggregate the IP addresses?
Yous should not have only one integer per record without any other group column, do you?
What DB do you use?

Comment: SQL Server 2005, yes I have only 1 column since im during a parsing method

Comment: but how do you distinguish several entries in your table then ?
How do you write the 2 following addresses: 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are doing something strangely when a parsed IP comes out as four rows.  It should be quite easy to parse directly to a row.  Could you perhaps provide your parsing method and/or input format?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with sheepsimulator's answer, but as you commented on my answer David, if you have no grouping column and several entries in your table it will be difficult to find a matching condition.
If you have only one IP entry (so 4 lines) then you can:

- use the lineID (rownum in Oracle) to group
- parse the 4 lines ;-)

EDIT: the first solution (using lineID) can be used to parse several IP entries, but it needs sequential inserts in the DB.